# Cypress : Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is on aws code build for ci

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cypress

I am trying to run cypress on codebuild pipeline for aws.

I am getting this error in aws codebuild pipeline :

```
[3039:0508/214055.907995:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is 

    tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

I tried to downgrade the cypress version from 9.6.0 to 9.2.0 but it didn't help me.

How can I solve this error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks